# php, change a db: from MySQL to txt file

Tags: php, mysql, email, text-files

I am newbie in Programming, I find this script and I'd like to adapt this to my needs, this script save the mail address on MySQL db but I'd like to save this on file txt, is possible re-use this code?

address.php

```
require "includes/connect.php";

$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
        }

        if($ajax){
            die('{"status":1}');
        }

        $msg = "Thank you!";

    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

where the connect.php is

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

@$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die('<h1>Could not connect to the database</h1><h2>Please try again after a few moments.</h2>');
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");


?>
```

Comment: No point in 'reusing' this, since perhaps 5% of this code is not related to database.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a complete rewrite

Answer (score 0):

That file is very specific to using a database.  However, using a file is not difficult.  I would suggest that rather than using a plain file, consider using a database like sqlite which uses files rather than a fully fledged database.

If you are set on using files, you can manipulate files very easily in php.  Some examples are below:

```
    $file = fopen('path/to/file', 'r+');

    fputs($file, 'email@domain.com'); 
    // fputs() is an alias for fwrite, they are interchangable
```

[This page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) details the different modes for opening a file with `fopen()`.  You will want to pay extra special attention to whether the mode opens the file pointer at the start or end of a file.  If you wrote some emails to the file, then later opened the file again with the file pointer at the start to write more emails, you would overwrite the existing data.  This is a good reason to use a database as it requires a bigger screw up to delete your existing data.

`fputs()` is used to write lines to your file.  Obviously you can pass a variable rather than the string I've put hard coded in the example, just make sure the variable is some meaningful string.  You can't, for example, pass an array of emails.  You would have to loop over the array and call `fputs()` for each email.

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse parts of it; the line that actually saves the data to the database is the line starting `$mysqli->query`, and the line afterward is the check for success. Remove those, and replace them with your own text file saving functions (and put those in an include file, rather than the given one which defines the mysqli connector).